# Download Jenkins plug-ins which got suspended by update center

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I need to download and use the [Scriptler plug-in](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Scriptler+Plugin) which unfortunately was suspended by Jenkins plug-in update center due to it's insecure issues. Is there anyway I can download it's .hip file or what other plug-ins can be it's substitution.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't find it , download the source code ,compile it and upload it to Jenkins

```
git clone git@github.com:jenkinsci/scriptler-plugin.git

mvn clean install
```

then load this file ito your Jenkins .**m2/repository/org/jenkins-ci/plugins/scriptler/2.10-SNAPSHOT/scriptler-2.10-SNAPSHOT.hpi**